# How to calculate this Jacobian determinant?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

Given that I have $u = x\cdot y$, and $v = \frac{y}{x}$.

How do I calculate the Jacobian determinant which should be:

$$J =\begin{vmatrix} \frac{dx}{du} & \frac{dx}{dv} \\  \frac{dy}{du} &  \frac{dy}{dv} \end{vmatrix}$$

Is there any good way to do this? Or do I just have to use $x = \sqrt{\frac{u}{v}}$, and $y = \sqrt{u\cdot v}$

Comment: Your function is $f(x,y) = (u(x,y), v(x,y))$.  You already have the expressions in the proper form for taking partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Thoth, Sorry I wrote the matrix wrong. Fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substitute and derive.  Also, those are partial derivatives

$$\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial y}{dv} \end{vmatrix}&=\begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial v}{dy} \end{vmatrix}^{-1}\\[2ex] &= \begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial xy}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial xy}{\partial y} \\ \dfrac{\partial  x^{-1}y }{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial x^{-1}y}{\partial y} \end{vmatrix}^{-1}\\[2ex] &= \left(\phantom{\begin{vmatrix}y & x \\ -x^{-2}y & x^{-1} \end{vmatrix}}\right)^{-1}\\[2ex]&=(\phantom{2x^{-1}y})^{-1}\\[2ex]&=\phantom{\tfrac 12v^{-1}}\end{align}
$$

Comment: Sorry I wrote the matrix wrong, it is fixed now, I wanted the opposite of what I wrote.

Comment: Okay, adjusted. @dondeman

Comment: Ah very nice! So it just becomes the inverse. Splendid! Thank you. Do you have any additional advice for spotting this the next time?

Comment: (this is using the inverse function theorem of multivariate calculus)